# How to maintain spaces while importing data from notepad/text

Tags: vba, text, notepad

I am importing data into excel from text file, but upon import the spacing changes. How to code so as to maintain the spacing same as text file. Basically I will use this spacing to convert text to columns.
Text file[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQM9H.png)

Upon import to excel[image]

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;C:\Users\1538544\Desktop\CIB\3\1114744500_A0000076849_SOIL.txt", _
        Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .Name = "1114744500_A0000076849_SOIL"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 932
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Well, what does your code look like? What does your text file look like?

Comment: That looks like just a difference between a non-proportional font and a proportional one.  There's no change in the actual data.  Try setting ColA font to (eg) Courier

Comment: @TimWilliams ... Newbie here..thanks